# Factura python basico

Tags: python, python-3.x

necesito un programa para crear una factura que coja un producto con un input y un precio luego lo multiplicaria pero en un bucle, es decir que no pare de pedir productos y precio hasta que presione X, de momento este es el codigo:

```
while True:
producto = input("Quin producte és: ")
cantidad = int(input("Cuanta quantitat: "))
precio = int(input("Quin preu es: "))
continuar = input("Presionar X para calcular: ")

if continuar == "X":
    total = cantidad * precio
    print("Productos: ", producto)
    print("Precio total: ",total)

    break
```

El bucle funciona pero no suma los productos solo el ultimo y quiero que muestre todos los productos y el precio total de todos los productos , con un bucle for no me funciona

Comment: `No suma los productos` .... bueno, no veo ninguna suma en ninguna parte; tampoco una estructura donde acumular los totales.

Comment: tal vez necesito un bucle for pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo por eso pido ayuda

Comment: Pues lo primero será empezar por mirar [cómo funcionan los bucles en python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) y probar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma en la que puedes atacar el problema es creando un diccionario que contenga los valores que vas insertando a través del input. De esta manera tienes control total.

Agregamos dos nuevas variables, la primera `dict` almacenará el producto, precio y cantidad, la segunda sumará el total de totales:

```
productos = {} #Guardamos los datos en un diccionario
total = 0 #Almacenará el total de totales
```

Dentro de tu `While` alimentamos el `dict` y aprovechamos para obtener el total de cada producto, de la siguiente forma:

```
productos[producto] = [producto, cantidad, precio, cantidad*precio]
```

Después lo que haremos es imprimir los productos en forma de lista, puedes transformarlos en lo que necesites:

```
print("Productos: ", list(productos.keys()))
```

Y finalmente sumamos los totales:

```
for i in productos.keys():
    total += productos[i][3] #Sumamos el total de cada producto
```

El código completo quedaría así:

```
productos = {} #Guardamos los datos en un diccionario
total = 0 #Almacenará el total de totales

while True:
    producto = input("Quin producte és: ")
    cantidad = int(input("Cuanta quantitat: "))
    precio = int(input("Quin preu es: "))
    continuar = input("Presionar X para calcular: ")
    productos[producto] = [producto, cantidad, precio, cantidad*precio] #Alimentamos el diccionario y de una vez calculamos el total por producto

    if continuar == "X":
        print("Productos: ", list(productos.keys())) #Mostramos los productos en forma de lista pero puedes hacerlo como quieras
        for i in productos.keys():
            total += productos[i][3] #Sumamos el total de cada producto
        break
print("Precio total: ",total) #Mostramos total de totales
```

Resultado:

```
Quin producte és: PC
Cuanta quantitat: 1
Quin preu es: 1000
Presionar X para calcular: 
Quin producte és: Movil
Cuanta quantitat: 1
Quin preu es: 1000
Presionar X para calcular: X
Productos:  ['PC', 'Movil']
Precio total:  2000
```

Ojalá esto te ayude. ¡Éxito!

Comment: ¿Por qué el código original estaba mal?

Comment: @Gabitohh no me parece que estaba mal. Atendí lo que preguntó al final del código. ¿Hice algo mal? :S

Comment: No hiciste nada mal, solo que sería mejor que explicaras que error estaba cometiendo el AP. ¿Por qué hiciste esos cambios?

Comment: Comprendo, @Gabitohh. He mejorado la introducción. Agradaceré tu feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando tu propio código, si deseas obtener el precio total de la factura, deberás inicializar una variable en 0 (que representará la suma acumulada), antes del `while` (en este caso es `total`). Dentro del ciclo, irás actualizando el valor del total con la multiplicación de la `cantidad*pecio` de forma acumulativa. Además, si dejas dentro de `if continuar == "X"` el cálculo de `cantidad*pecio`, entonces sólo calculará el del último elemento. Por otra parte, si tu intención es mostrar todos los productos, deberás utilizar una estructura (lista, diccionario, tupla, etc.) que te permita ir almacenándolos para luego mostrarlos todos, si no, se mostrará sólo el último producto.

```
# Para mostrar productos y precio total:
print("Para mostrar productos y precio total:")
total = 0
productos=[]
while True:
    producto = input("Quin producte és: ")
    productos.append(producto)
    cantidad = int(input("Cuanta quantitat: "))
    precio = float(input("Quin preu es: "))
    subtotal=round(cantidad * precio, 2)
    total+=subtotal
    continuar = input("Presionar X para calcular o enter para continuar: ")

    if continuar == "X":
        print("Productos: ", productos)
        print("Precio total: ", total)
        break
```

Otras soluciones (aunque corrigiendo los detalles de tu código, el primero sirve igual):

```
# Para mostrar productos, precio por cada unidad, subtotal y precio total:
print("\nPara mostrar productos, precio por cada unidad, subtotal y precio total:")
total = 0
productos=[]
while True:
    producto = input("Quin producte és: ")
    cantidad = int(input("Cuanta quantitat: "))
    precio = float(input("Quin preu es: "))
    subtotal=round(cantidad * precio, 2)
    total += subtotal
    productos.append((producto+" --> Cantidad: "+str(cantidad)+" unidades --> Precio c/u: "+str(precio)+" pesos --> Subtotal: "+str(subtotal)+" pesos"))
    continuar = input("Presionar X para calcular o enter para continuar: ")
    if continuar == "X":
        print("Productos: ")
        [print("-",p) for p in productos]
        print("Precio total:", round(total,2),"pesos")
        break

# Con diccionario
print("\nCon diccionario:")
total = 0
productos={}
while True:
    producto = input("Quin producte és: ")
    cantidad = int(input("Cuanta quantitat: "))
    precio = float(input("Quin preu es: "))
    subtotal=round(cantidad * precio, 2)
    total += subtotal
    productos[producto]=(cantidad,precio,subtotal)
    continuar = input("Presionar X para calcular o enter para continuar: ")
    if continuar == "X":
        print("Productos: ")
        [print("-",p,"--> Cantidad:",productos[p][0],"unidades --> Precio c/u:",productos[p][2],"pesos --> Subtotal:",productos[p][2],"pesos") for p in productos]
        print("Forma #1 de obtener total:")
        print("Precio total:", round(total, 2), "pesos")
        print("Forma #2 de obtener total:")
        print("Precio total:", round(sum(productos[p][2] for p in productos),2), "pesos")        
        break
```

Muestra de qué imprimen los tres ejemplos:

```
Para mostrar productos y precio total:
Quin producte és: Manzana
Cuanta quantitat: 25
Quin preu es: 3.7
Presionar X para calcular o enter para continuar: 
Quin producte és: Pera
Cuanta quantitat: 87
Quin preu es: 7.25
Presionar X para calcular o enter para continuar: X
Productos:  ['Manzana', 'Pera']
Precio total:  723.25

Para mostrar productos, precio por cada unidad, subtotal y precio total:
Quin producte és: Manzana
Cuanta quantitat: 25      
Quin preu es: 3.7
Presionar X para calcular o enter para continuar:      
Quin producte és: Pera    
Cuanta quantitat: 87   
Quin preu es: 7.25
Presionar X para calcular o enter para continuar: X
Productos: 
- Manzana --> Cantidad: 25 unidades --> Precio c/u: 3.7 pesos --> Subtotal: 92.5 pesos
- Pera --> Cantidad: 87 unidades --> Precio c/u: 7.25 pesos --> Subtotal: 630.75 pesos
Precio total: 723.25 pesos

Con diccionario:
Quin producte és: Manzana
Cuanta quantitat: 25      
Quin preu es: 3.7
Presionar X para calcular o enter para continuar: 
Quin producte és: Pera
Cuanta quantitat: 87
Quin preu es: 7.25
Presionar X para calcular o enter para continuar: X
Productos: 
- Manzana --> Cantidad: 25 unidades --> Precio c/u: 92.5 pesos --> Subtotal: 92.5 pesos
- Pera --> Cantidad: 87 unidades --> Precio c/u: 630.75 pesos --> Subtotal: 630.75 pesos
Forma #1 de obtener total:
Precio total: 723.25 pesos
Forma #2 de obtener total:
Precio total: 723.25 pesos
```